Equivalence for a matrix to be symmetric
Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ with the QR-decomposition $A=QR$ ($Q$ orthogonal, $R$ upper triangular matrix). I asked myself if the following statement holds:
$$A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}\text{ symmetric}\Longleftrightarrow Q\sigma R\text{ symmetric for all }\sigma\text{ with the following form}$$
$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix}\pm 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 & \pm 1 & 0 & \vdots \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \ldots & 0 & \pm1 \end{pmatrix}\subseteq O(n)$. So maybe someone has a proof or a contradiction.

This definitely isn’t true. Let $A$ be any symmetric orthogonal matrix. Then $A=QR$ is a QR-decomposition when we take $Q=A$ and $R=I$. If $n>1$ and $a_{1n}\ne0$, then $Q\operatorname{diag}(1,\ldots,1,-1)R$ is not symmetric.
